# React-Redux action won't dispatch to the reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am having an issue where my action won't enter into my return statement.  I have copied the code more or less from a project that I have already worked on and know that it works.  If there are any redux masters out there help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import * as types from '../Constants/Action_Types'
import axios from 'axios'

export function getSingleReport(){
    console.log("in the action")
    return function (dispatch) {
        console.log("in the action return function")
        axios.get('/api/report-single/57b3aba0aa676af0a3db6250').then((result) => dispatch({
            type: types.GET_SINGLE_REPORT,
            reportTitle: result.data.title,
            reportAuthor: result.data.author  
        }))
    }

}
```

I will hit the first conole.log statement but not the second.  Why does the action decide to stop working at the return function (dispatch) { line?

As requested here is the reducer as well.

```
import { GET_SINGLE_REPORT } from '../Constants/Action_Types'

const initialState = {
    reportTitle: "Title of Report",
    reportAuthor: "Author of Report"
}

export default function populateReport(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log("in the reducer")
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_SINGLE_REPORT:
        console.log("in the get GET_SINGLE_REPORT reducer")
        return {
            ...state,
            reportTitle: action.reportTitle,
            reportAuthor: action.reportAuthor
        }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Without context it's impossible to help. Maybe you're not calling the returned function?

Comment: do you have `redux-thunk` middleware configured?  Sounds like this project doesn't have the proper middleware that the old project has.

Comment: I do have thunk middleware configured.  The second console should print before the asynchronous call is made

Comment: Can we see your reducer please?

Comment: can you post the code from your middleware?

Comment: did you try putting a catch on your axios request? your request could be failing

Comment: Confirm your api is responding with `200 series`?

Comment: So I never reach the axios.get call as the second console.log never prints

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing and calling your getSingleReport function?  It is very easy to err when dealing with imported functions that return functions, and end up calling them incorrectly.  The fact that the second console.log never gets executed implies to me that the returned function is never executed.  Whichever file uses the code you posted needs to look something like...

```
import {getSingleReport} from './yourScriptLocation'

const dispatchSingleReport = getSingleReport();

const dispatch = // wherever your dispatch comes from, doesn't really matter

dispatchSingleReport(dispatch);
```

If you just call the imported function, like below, then that would explain the behaviour you are seeing, as the returned function will be discarded.

```
import {getSingleReport} from './yourScriptLocation'

const dispatch = // wherever your dispatch comes from, doesn't really matter

getSingleReport(dispatch);
```